# Re-arrange huge number of dictionaries based on group id

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to re-arrange below array of dictionaries:

```
(
  {
   name : "aaa"
   group_id : 1.1
  },
  {
   name : "bbb"
   group_id : 1.2
  },
  {
   name : "ccc"
   group_id : 1.1
  },
  {
   name : "ddd"
   group_id : 1.2
  },
  {
   name : "aaa"
   group_id : 1.3
  },
  ...
)
```

TO this:

```
(
  (
   {
    name : "aaa"
    group_id : 1.1
   },
   {
    name : "ccc"
    group_id : 1.1
   }
  ),
  (
   {
    name : "bbb"
    group_id : 1.2
   },
   {
    name : "ddd"
    group_id : 1.2
   }
  ),
  {
   name : "aaa"
   group_id : 1.3
  },
  ...
)
```

The array of dictionaries need to be re-arranged is of count more than 1500. Need to re-arrange this as fast as possible.

I am using this:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)filterForAnnotationsWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)originalArray{

    NSMutableArray *requiredArr = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *indexesArr = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *tempRemovingIndexesArr = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *filteringArr1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[removeNullValues removeNullinData:originalArray]];

    for (int i=0; i<originalArray.count; i++) {
        [indexesArr removeAllObjects];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in filteringArr1) {
            if ([[dict valueForKey:@"group_id"] isEqualToString:[[originalArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"group_id"]]) {
                if (![tempRemovingIndexesArr containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[filteringArr1 indexOfObject:dict]]]) {
                    [indexesArr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[filteringArr1 indexOfObject:dict]]];
                    [tempRemovingIndexesArr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[filteringArr1 indexOfObject:dict]]];
                }
            }
            if ([filteringArr1 indexOfObject:dict] == filteringArr1.count-1) {
                if (indexesArr.count>1) {
                    NSMutableArray *searchedArr = [NSMutableArray array];
                    for (NSString *str in indexesArr) {
                        [searchedArr addObject:[originalArray objectAtIndex:str.intValue]];
                    }
                    [requiredArr addObject:searchedArr];
                }
                else if(indexesArr.count == 1){
                    [requiredArr addObject:[originalArray objectAtIndex:[[indexesArr objectAtIndex:0] intValue]]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return requiredArr;
}
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Please check the updated question @Avi.

Comment: samo, samo, samo, boring, boring, boring...  Run a search for 'NSArray sort.'

Comment: i did. I've worked on sort descriptors too. nothing gave me result what i've expected.

Comment: As I understand, result array should contain mix of arrays and dictionaries. It doesn't look right. Consider wrap single dictionaries to arrays too, it would be much easier to work with resulting array then.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ Boris Verebsky, but I need some help in form of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution with is much faster than what I've used earlier.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)filterForAnnotationsWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)originalArray{
    NSMutableArray *tempRemovingIndexesArr = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *filteringArr1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[removeNullValues removeNullinData:originalArray]];

    for (int i=0; i<originalArray.count; i++) {
        if (i!=0) {
            NSArray *filteredarray2 = [filteringArr1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(group_id != %@)", [[filteringArr1 objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"group_id"]]];
            [filteringArr1 removeAllObjects];
            if (filteredarray2.count>0) {
                [filteringArr1 addObjectsFromArray:filteredarray2];
            }
        }
        if (filteringArr1.count>0) {
            NSArray *filteredarray = [filteringArr1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(group_id == %@)", [[filteringArr1 objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"group_id"]]];
            if (filteredarray.count>0) {
                if (filteredarray.count == 1) {
                    [tempRemovingIndexesArr addObjectsFromArray:filteredarray];
                }
                else{
                    [tempRemovingIndexesArr addObject:filteredarray];
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            return tempRemovingIndexesArr;
        }
    return originalArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I'm somewhat baffled by your code, it is an unusual attempt at sorting and only references the key `group_id` yet for sample input/output indicate a 2-key sort with `group_id` as the primary key and `name` as the secondary key.

Of course, while sorting may still be CS 201, these days you don't need to implement the sorting algorithm yourself as just about every standard library provides an implementation. Cocoa is no exception, and `NSArray` has the `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method that should fit your need - it sorts an array of *anything* by using a function you supply which compares two elements of the array and returns their order according to your desired sort.

The function must return a value of `NSComparisonResult`, a value type with the three values `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedSame`, and `NSOrderedDescending`. Cocoa also supplies a bunch of methods in the `compare` family which return an `NSComparisonResult` value.

Now you want a 2-key sort. In any n-key sort you first compare the values of the first key, if they are equal (`NSOrderedSame`) then you move onto the next key and compare that one. You repeat this as long as values of the keys are equal or you run out of keys. For just two keys in pseudo code this is:

```
NSComparisonResult order = compare key1 of object1 and object2;
if (order is NSOrderedSame) order = compare key2 of object1 and object2;
return order;
```

That just leaves how you compare each key. Well both are `NSString` values, and `NSString` has a number of methods in the `compare` family. For your primary key, `group_id`, the numeric value of the string is what determines the order, so you'll want a `compare` family method which takes numeric value into account - try `compare:options:`.

Combine the above and you should have your answer in a few lines. If you try it and get stuck ask another question showing the code you've produced and explain why you're stuck. Somebody will probably be able to help.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply @CRD